# Python 3: message error when I try to open a pdf

Tags: python, pdf, encoding, pypdf

I'm having issues with code that used to work during weeks.

The problem comes from this part of my code:

```
TypeError: ifile  = open('0_Inputs/CompaniesList.csv', "r", encoding = 'utf-8')
```

I got the following message:

```
open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

If i try:

```
ifile  = open('0_Inputs/CompaniesList.csv', "r")
```

then i have an other error:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file '0_Inputs/CompaniesList.csv'
```

Im doing `from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter` but I don't if there's a conflict between libraries?

Thank you!

Comment: You are asking about opening PDFs, but you are trying to open a csv? Is the `open()` function you are referring to the built in open?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `csv` module instead of opening the file this way.

```
with open('0_Inputs/CompaniesList.csv', newline='') as ifile:
    pass
```

More information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Thank you for answering. I got this: TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'newline'

Comment: Did you load the `csv` module? Are you running Python 3?

Comment: I did import csv, and I'm running Python 3.6. I can't find where is the problem with 
 the open function.  Can it be a conflict with Image from the pillow library?

Comment: Just delete this argument so… But it is very strange.